# Python-Bottle, form is too big in the main app.py

Tags: python, bottle

I'm new to programming and I am doing a Webbapp with bottle. I'm doing the request part right now but my tutor told me is quite messy. How can I improve or make @route cleaner?  My code:

'''

```
from bottle import run, template, route, request
from PlanetDestination import price
from database import dataInput

#Global variables will be used for other routes
formDateTime = ""  
formPlanet = ""
formSeat = ""
formFood = ""

@route('/information', method=['GET', 'POST'])
def passangers():
   if request.method == 'POST':  
     global formDateTime
     global formPlanet
     global formSeat
     global formFood
     #calling variables from Frontend
     firstName = request.forms.get('firstName')  
     lastName = request.forms.get('lastName')
     birthD = request.forms.get('birthD')
     adress = request.forms.get('adress')
     email = request.forms.get('email')
     phone = request.forms.get('phone')
     payment = request.forms.get('payment')
     ticketP = price(formPlanet, formSeat)# calling the function to generate final prices 
     data = (firstName, lastName, birthD, adress, email, phone, payment, formDateTime, 
       formPlanet, formSeat, formFood, ticketP)
     dataInput(data) #Sends the data to sqlite database
     formDateTime = ""
     formPlanet = ""
     redirect ('/confirmation')
   else:
     return template('templatePersonalData')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option for cache with caveat:
There is a problem here, as soon as your webserver becomes async this will not work due to race conditions.  My suggestion is not cache, and instead pull from a database.

```
#Global variables will be used for other routes
cache = {}
@route('/information', method=['GET', 'POST'])
def passangers():
   if request.method == 'POST':  
     global cache
     form = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'birthD','address','email','phone','payment', 'formDateTime', 'formPlanet', 'formSeat', 'formFood']
     #calling variables from Frontend
     for f in form:
         cache[f] = request.forms.get(f, '')
     cache['ticketP'] = price(cache['formPlanet'], cache['formSeat'])# calling the function to generate final prices 
     dataInput(cache) #Sends the data to sqlite database
     redirect ('/confirmation')
   else:
     return template('templatePersonalData')
```